# How to insert a row in a nested table in Oracle with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, nested-table

I created 2 types as OBJECT and a type of table and a nested table in my Oracle database. I know how to inset a row in table in cmd but I have no idea that how I can insert a row in this table with `PreparedStatement` in Java.
This is my table and type:

```
 CREATE Or REPLACE TYPE item AS OBJECT
( 
  id        number,
  counter   number
);/
CREATE Or REPLACE TYPE time AS OBJECT
( 
  year        number,
  month number,
  second number
);
CREATE Or REPLACE TYPE Shoping_list AS TABLE OF item;
create table invoice(
id number NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
list shoping_list,
dateIn date,
timeIn time,
totalCost number )
nested table list store as list_of_product;
```

I can insert with this code in cmd

```
insert into invoice(id,list,dateIn,timeIn,totalCost) values(seq_ID_invoice.nextval,
shoping_list(item(1,2),item(26,1)),TO_DATE('1396-04-11','YYYY-MM-DD'),time(11,25,40),7000);
```

and this my java code

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into invoice (id,list,dateIn,timeIn,totalCost) values ("+id+",?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `timeIn`, resp. `TIME` type? A `DATE` data type value always include the time part.

Comment: when i write time as a data type I see this error : "invalid data type"

Comment: Yes, simply there is no `TIME` date type in Oracle. It is all in `DATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seq_ID_invoice` is Oracle Sequence. So oracle takes its value automatically. For rest you can use `setInt, setString, setFloat, etc. methods` available in `PreparedStatement` based on the types of columns defined inside your table.

Following sample code may help you.

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "insert into invoice(id, list, dateIn, timeIn, totalCost)"+
    " values (seq_ID_invoice.nextval, shoping_list(item(?,?), item(?,?)), TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD'), time(?, ?, ?), ?)");

ps.setInt(1, int_value_for_id_of_item_1);
ps.setInt(2, int_value_for_counter_of_item_1);
ps.setInt(3, int_value_for_id_of_item_2);
ps.setInt(4, int_value_for_counter_of_item_2);
ps.setString(5, string_value_for_date);
ps.setInt(6, int_value_for_year_of_time);
ps.setInt(7, int_value_for_month_of_time);
ps.setInt(8, int_value_for_second_of_time);
ps.setInt(9, int_bvalue_for_total_cost);

int rowCnt = ps.executeUpdate();  
System.out.println(rowCnt+" rows affected.");
```

`int_value_for_id_of_item_1, int_value_for_counter_of_item_1, ...` these are java variables. You can defined variables of your choice or you can directly mention values in place of these variables.

Comment: thank you.but the number of items in shoping_list is not always two (fixed).

Comment: You can do `setInt` those many times per no. of items inside list. 1,2,3,... are indexes of parameters and they will increase or decrease as per your need. These index numbers must be equal to no. of `?` in your query. For example, in above query there are 9 `?`. Means we are setting values for 9 entities and hence index has reached to 9.